# Why doesn't rails need to be restarted after I modify the controllers? Does such thing exist in Python web framework?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

Rails does not need to be restarted after I modify the codes in views and controllers. Do such features also exist in Python web framework?

I tried Flask and Pyramid before. I know they don't need to be restarted if I only changed the `template`, but have to be restarted if I changed the `views`(which are similar to `controllers` in `rails`). And the restart takes a few seconds to finish.

As I remember, `rails` doesn't need to be restarted even when I changed codes in `controllers`. Does anyone have ideas about whether such feature also exists in Python web framework?

Comment: This isn't a really constructive question. Have you tried to use any of the frameworks you tagged? Did you run into any problems with any of those?

Comment: @MartijnPieters You don't catch what I mean. I know how to make `Pyramid` and `Flask` to **RESTART AUTOMATICALLY** after changing codes. But it seemed that **RAILS DOESNOT NEED TO RESTART**, even I changed the codes for `controllers`.

Comment: @Firegun, if I understand the question correctly, it seems as though you are asking for a product recommendation which is not fit for SO. Such a question is likely to solicit debate.

Comment: @TylerCrompton I'm a newcomer to web development. I tried both rails and some python web framework. I'm just wondering that why rails provide this feature(no restarting instead of automatical restarting) but Python web framwwork doesn't provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails implements development-time reloading as follows. There are two mechanisms at work.

1. Whenever the code references a class that does not exist, a callback (const_missing) can be called. Rails installs such a callback. In this callback it checks whether there is a corresponding class in one of the application load paths (e.g. in app/models), loads it and carries on. This mechanism is called "Rails autoloading" (not to be confused to Ruby autoloading which is something different).
2. Rails tracks which classes have been autoloaded. At the end of the request, it removes all those classes from memory.

Obviously this has some limitations. If your code stores stuff in global variables then Rails will not clear them at the end of the request, so if you global variables keep growing you will leak memory during development. Reloading also causes subtle differences in semantics between development in production. Whereas something like

```
scope :older_than_one_year, where('date < ?', 1.year.ago)
```

works as intended in development (because the model is reloaded on each request, causing 1.year.ago to be constantly re-evaluated), it doesn't work as intended in production (because the 1.year.ago is only evaluated once, so if your app has been running for a year then that scope actually translates to *2 years* ago).

I don't know whether something can be implemented in Python, I'm not familiar with Python's on-the-fly class creation/modification/removal capabilities or whether it has any hooks similar to const_missing.

Answer (score 3):

Pyramid has an [option](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/project.html#reloading-code) to automatically restart the server after changing a file:

`pserve development.ini --reload`

I'm sure each projects documentation provides an anser to your question

Django does as well (which you didn't ask for in your question)

Comment: But it take a few seconds to restart. In rails, it doesn't need to restart at all as I remembered.